# Pass Angularjs $index into onchange with ng repeat and input type is file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi i am very new to Angularjs  .I am creating a table row using ng repeat  ,row contains input type file so I wants to upload different file from different row . I wants to pass index for each row with onchange method .but index always return zero .
Code snippet

```
input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)" 

scope.file_changed = function (element) { 
var index = angular.element(element).scope().$index;
var files = element.files;

};
```

Comment: how your controller looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what's the intention behind of calling **file_changed()** method using **angular.element**. It's not the right approach in angular js. If this method already in your controller scope , you can access directly access from the html like below and you can pass $index as a parameter in to the method.

```
 <div ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
    <input type="file" onchange="file_changed(this,$index)" 
  </div>
```

I am assuming your controller will like this

```
  app.controller('YourController', function($scope) {
       $scope.file_changed=function(element,index){ 
            var files = element.files;
       }  
});
```

Comment: Yes my controller is same like you have define above .I tried the solution you provided above  but this did not help .throws this exception. In the following code I get 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $index is not defined' .

Comment: In the onchange attribute, the scope is only accessible via angular.element(this).scope().

Comment: @Suri did you try with track by $index in ng-repeat explicitly? check my answer

Comment: @Suri you are welcome. you can mark it as an answer if it’s works